# Change innerHTML based on date comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I currently have the following code showing:

```
<h1  id="header1" class="loginhead">Welcome to the <%=formFields.getDisplayValue("programName")%> Registration Site, .</h1>
```

I need to replace it with:

```
<h1  id="header2" class="loginhead" >The <%=formFields.getDisplayValue("programName")%> Registration Site, is now closed.</h1>
```

I need the replace to happen when the date and time are `7/15/15 11:59PM PT`

Any way to do this using **Jquery**, **JSP** or **Javascript**?

Update**

```
    <h1  id="header" class="loginhead" ><span id='welcome'></span><span id='welcome2'></span> <%=formFields.getDisplayValue("programName")%> Registration Site <span id='closed'></span> </h1> 
<script>
 var now = new Date().getTime(); //Return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:

var epochTimeJul15_1159pm = 1437019199000; // number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 at Jul 15_11:59:59pm. See http://www.epochconverter.com/.

var timeTillChange = epochTimeJul15_1159pm - now;

function changeHeader(){
    document.getElementById('closed').innerHTML = ' is now closed.'; //change the html/text inside of the span with the id closed'.
}

function changeHeader1()
{
    if(epochTimeJul15_1159pm <= now) 
    {
        document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML = 'The ';
    }
}

function changeHeader2()
{
    if(now < epochTimeJul15_1159pm) 
    {
        document.getElementById('welcome2').innerHTML = 'Welcome to the '; 
    }
}
setTimeout(changeHeader, timeTillChange); //will wait to call changeHeader function until timeTillChange milliseconds have occured.
setTimeout(changeHeader1, timeTillChange); 
setTimeout(changeHeader2, timeTillChange);
</script>
```

Comment: `7/15/15 11:59PM` this date will be static?

Comment: Yes.. But it is Pacific Standard Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make it easier to use javascript to edit your html. We will do this by creating an empty span to insert the closed message into:

```
<h1  id="header" class="loginhead" >Welcome to the <%=formFields.getDisplayValue("programName")%> Registration Site <span id='closed'></span> </h1>
```

Now in your javascript section:

```
var now = new Date().getTime(); //Return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:

var epochTimeJul15_1159pm = 1437019199000; // number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 at Jul 15_11:59:59pm. See http://www.epochconverter.com/.

var timeTillChange = epochTimeJul15_1159pm - now;

function changeHeader(){
    document.getElementById('closed').innerHTML = ' is now closed.'; //change the html/text inside of the span with the id closed'.
}

setTimeout(changeHeader, timeTillChange); //will wait to call changeHeader function until timeTillChange milliseconds have occured.
```

This will make the header get edited live as soon as the clock hits 11:59:59.

Comment: The original text was " Welcome to the <%=formFields.getDisplayValue("programName")%> Registration Site, .... How do I get the "Welcome to" part to disappear after the selected time has passed?

Comment: ^^Thanks, I misread the original text. I have edited my answer. Regarding getting the welcome message to dissapear, think a bit: What did I do to get the ' is now closed' part to appear after the selected time has passed?

Comment: Ok so I put this code in.. But its not working exactly as I want it to.. Any chance you can help me out with it?.... I'm going to add it in the code block above. The welcome2 is not working correctly, but the welcome is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($.now >= dateLimit){
    $("#header1").hide(0);
    $("#header2").show(0);
}
```

This would be a general jquery way to do this, you could setup the two elements to be hidden or shown accordingly in your css.

This would do it upon page load, I am not exactly sure how to implement a dynamic version of this.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can do dynamically with JavaScript. [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kZM1LzGwwPTFpeKnyc4P?p=preview)

You can just compare two `date` and change `innerHTML` of `header`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function setHeader(){
            var d1 = new Date("7/15/15 11:57"); // change your dates here
            var d2 = new Date("7/15/15 11:58"); // change your dates here
            var header = document.getElementById("header");
            if(d1 > d2){
                header.innerHTML = "Welcome to the " + <%=formFields.getDisplayValue("programName")%> + " Registration Site."
            } else {
                header.innerHTML = "Welcome to the " + <%=formFields.getDisplayValue("programName")%> + " Registration Site, is now closed. "
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>

<body onload="setHeader()">
    <h1  id="header" class="loginhead"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work unless the user refreshes the page at midnight.